# taking double quotes with each paramaeters

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using this JavaScript method to generate a url in a View.

```
var url = '@Html.Raw(Url.Action("NewAPIForm", "Developer",
    new { ClientSecret ="test", clientID = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(TempData["ClientID"])),
    AppName = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(TempData["appname"])),
    Email = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(TempData["email"])) }))';
```

hoping to get a result like this:

```
/Developer/NewAPIForm?ClientSecret=test&clientID=AP-QIYYL1B8&AppName=Test&Email=a%40gmail.com
```

but it's showing:

```
/Developer/NewAPIForm?ClientSecret=%228Ke4QYPctENcca0F1og5zZRpdlt5XuBa68gkSSN5hbCjYPaB%22&clientID=%22AP-26GKQJ86%22&AppName=%22Test%22&Email=%22a%40gmail.com%22
```

How can I generate the url I am after, and get rid of `%22` in the current result? Thanks.

Comment: Please, stop referring to "ASP.NET MVC" simply as "MVC". One is a framework, while other is a language-independent design pattern. It's like calling IE - "the internet"

Comment: I am not a ASP expert but by seeing your code try removing the double quotes because the %22 stands for double quote..

Comment: @tereško Are you saying that IE is not "the internet"? This is a screenshot of my desktop right now: [https://www.groovypost.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/clip_image0041.jpg]. When I click "The Internet", IE opens!